# Do nodes in Spark Cluster share the same storage?

Tags: apache-spark, azure-databricks

I a newbie to spark. I am using `Azure Databricks` and I am writing python code with `PySpark`. There is one particular topic which is confusing me:

Do nodes have separate storage memory (I don't mean RAM/cache)? Or they all share the same storage? If they share the same storage, then can two different applications running in different `Spark Context` exchange data accordingly?

I don't understand why sometime we refer to the storage by `dbfs:/tmp/...`, and other times we refer to it by `/dbfs/tmp/`... Example: If I am using the `dbutils` package from databricks, we use something like: `dbfs:/tmp/...` to refer to a directory in the file system. However, if I'm using regular python code, I say `/dbfs/tmp/`.

Your help is much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each node has separate RAM memory and caching. For example, if you have a cluster with 4GB and 3 nodes. When you deploy your spark application, it will run worker processes depending on cluster configuration and query requirements and it will create virtual machines on separate nodes or on same node. These node memories are not shared between each other during the life of the application.

This is more about Hadoop resource sharing question and can find more information from YARN resource management. This is very brief overview 
https://databricks.com/session/resource-management-and-spark-as-a-first-class-data-processing-framework-on-hadoop

Comment: thank you @Piyush for your answer. From your answer, I understand that the worker nodes have different memory storages. So do you mean they don't share any memory? And what about the dbfs part?

Comment: @I.A Yes, workers don't share memory and they should not for parallel processing otherwise one process might conflict updates made by another. dbfs is mounted file system. You can read more https://docs.databricks.com/data/databricks-file-system.html. 

If this answers your question, please vote.

Comment: Thank you again @Piyush, I would like to know one more thing. Is this file system (DBFS) accessible by all worker nodes. Or, is it the storage where the worker nodes save their data into? Maybe, I will assume that this file system is partitioned as well and the number of partitions is equal to the number of worker nodes. Not sure if this is correct or not. If you please, can you elaborate on dbfs? I read the link you provide but yet some concepts are not clear. Your help is much appreciated!!

Comment: I dont know the underlying concept but it seems like mounting HDFS on edge location. It seems similar. I don't work on Databricks. So, mounting is like when you mount, your HDFS appears on your local file system. So, you can treat it very much like local FS. DBFS seems like that I think. Sorry, my knowledge is limited with DBFS.